# android studio not starting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

i get this error when starting android studio

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.loadDescriptors()[Lcom/intellij/ide/plugins/IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl;
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:121)
at com.a.a.b.b.ar.a(ar.java:71)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:19)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.startApp(StartupUtil.java:303)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareApp(StartupUtil.java:245)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:47)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) .... JRE 1.8.0_242 release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o ***/opt/android-studio-ide-201.6858069-linux/android-studio/jre/jre
```

my operating system is ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64bit

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I don't know what caused this but sdkmanager is also not working and shows `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema` this error.

Comment: Just use JetBrains toolbox https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/ to install Android studio, and everything should work out of a box.

Comment: I had to delete the android studio's user config folder in ~/.local/share/Google to fix the issue.

Comment: There's a glitch in 4.1 on some systems. Use canary instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i dont know what cause this issue but run it as sudo solve it .
your installation directory is /opt so run this command on terminal

```
sudo ./opt/androidStudioDirectory/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: This is not the correct solution. Running in sudo does solve this problem but no tools are working without root permissions. We cannot run SDKs like Flutter with root privileges.

Comment: Running it as root is not a good solution. Root is very powerful, and should never be used when it isn't required (like in this situation).

Just like @SyedMushaheed said, using `sudo` can also break some SDKs / tools.

Comment: Instead of running Android Studio as root try out [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035000/2163155)

Answer (score 7):

I first encountered this issue after updating my Android Studio to 4.0.1 allbeit on a **MacOS**.
To fix this issue, please take the following steps:

1. Go to the directory `~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio`
2. You would find `marketplace` folder in this location.
3. Rename this folder and attempt starting Android Studio again.
4. When Android Studio starts up again, go to `Android Studio -> Preferences`
5. Goto `Plugins` and click `installed`.
6. The incompatible plugins would surface at this stage. Click delete/uninstall for these plugins.
7. Restart the IDE and all should be perfect.

Answer (score 4):

That error indicates an issue in IDE plugins.

Remove the Android Studio folder in `~/.local/share/Google/`.

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my machine. It was solved by deleting the `plugins` folder located in `.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio/ch-0/201.6953283.plugins/marketplace`. Note that **201.6953283** was my current version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the canary build until Google releases v4.2. This worked for me. Just open software install and search for "android studio canary."

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after upgrading from Android Studio 4.0.1 to 4.1.1, but solved it by deleting some plugins under the directory `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`. The plugins I deleted were:

```
idea-multimarkdown
Gauge-Java-Intellij
markdown
marketplace
```